# Generated new cryptocoin but how to get balance in my account?

Tags: currencies, ico-initial-coin-offering

I have created new Cryptocurrency from litecoin's fork.

And I can connect more than 2 node with successfully.

But How to pull original balance in my wallet?

Let me share screenshot: https://ibb.co/gci8kn

Balance: 0
Unconfirmed: 0
Immature: 120 MIND.

How to transfer amount 120 MIND in original balance?

I did "setgenerate true" from debug window but it increases only Immature amount.

Please let me know about it. It is very important for it.

Comment: Don't you have to mine some blocks first, to create coins?

Comment: @OsiasJota No, I don't have any mine. How to mine amount in my wallet? I create wallet from litecoin fork

Comment: You should also fork a mining software and mine some blocks. Maybe the fork you did is already capable of doing that, but I never used Litecoin and can't tell how to put it to mine, I don't where to find this command or menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coins that are immature mean that you have not mined enough blocks for them to be spendable yet. If you did not change the `COINBASE_MATURITY` global variable, then you will need to mine 100 blocks before the immature coins become mature and spendable. Of course the process of mining produces new coins, so your immature balance will increase until you have mined 100 blocks.

Comment: @moderator I have changed COINBASE_MATURITY=10 to 100 and again compile my coin using "make" command but still it is display in immature and 
>>  as per you told "then you will need to mine 100 blocks" --> How to do this?

Comment: You actually have to mine 1 block more than COINBASE_MATURITY in order for it to become mature. To mine blocks, use the `setgenerate` or `generate` commands.

Comment: @moderator: I have used "setgenerate true" function from debug mode but it is increasing only immature balance Let me share screenshot https://ibb.co/djjV0n

Comment: Increasing the immature balance means that it is mining blocks. Just wait a while and eventually those will become mature coins. Use `getblockchaininfo` and you will see how many blocks are in your blockchain. After a while, when you see your immature balance increase, use `getblockchaininfo` again and you should see that the blockchain has grown.

Comment: @moderator: Is there any other way to do mine my coin? like setup own mining and mine the block? something like that: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1762002.0

Comment: You can use any mining software that uses the `getblocktemplate` protocol. Most modern mining software (and even old ones like cpuminer) support that. It won't really matter once the difficulty adjusts though.